# Leaflet js: Changing the size of the geocoder control

Tags: javascript, html, css, leaflet

I want to change the size of geocoder control on the map I created:

```
L.Control.geocoder().addTo(Map)
```

[image: change the size of the search button]

Comment: Have you tried to change the size with css?

Comment: I m not sure how to do it with css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your css:

```
.leaflet-control-geocoder-form input{
   width: 500px !important;
}
```

Comment: Didn't change anything.

Comment: try it with `!important`

Comment: Thank you i just figured how to fix it but the important fix did the trick too thank you